Is there a Ruby on Rails form_for equivalent on .net mvc
I want to create a nested form just like on ruby on rails form_for for my view using .net mvc.
I have a models that has one to many relationship.
// Principal (parent)
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set;}
}

// Dependent (child)
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

and I have this view model:
public class CreateBlogVM
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set;}
}

and a GET Request action that initialize the Posts
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<CreateBlogVM> Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateBlogVM()
    {
        Posts = [new Posts { Title = "" }]

    };
    return View(vm);
}

On my view I wanted to create a nested form for the posts properties just like in ruby on rails
@model CreateBlogVM

<form asp method="post" asp-action="Create">
  <div class="form-group col-4">
     <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
     <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>

   @foreach (var post in @Model.Posts)
   {
     <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label asp-for="@post.Title" class="control-label">Title:</label>
        <input asp-for="@post.Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@post.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
     </div>  
   }
</form>

Validating the POST request I see no posts. Am I missing something? I was trying to look for a documentation about nested forms or nested view models.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateBlogVM model)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join("-", model.Posts)}"); <--- throws an error because Posts here is null
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      await _blogService.Create(model);
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
   }
   return View(model);
}

UPDATE:
OK upon investigating. I just found out that the request is null because data its being sent like this:
Title: ""

and html is being formatted like this.
<input name="Title" class="form-control" />

HTML should be like this. The name property should be like in array format
<input name="Posts[0].Title" class="form-control" />

So I think I have to do it manually since .net mvc doesnt support something like this.
The way I'm thinking to do it and the only way is thru JQuery.

My best guess is that ICollection<Post> should be changed to List<Post> or something that supports indexing i.e. Posts[0], Posts[1] ....

Maybe you miss Include statement in model loading from DbContext?
For example:
var model = _context.Blogs
    .Include(x => x.Posts) // <-- that line
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.id);

Or, if you really constructing an object in controller without DbContext try to use Dto as View Model with List<Post> property.
For example:
public sealed record BlogDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public List<PostDto> Posts { get; set;}
}
public sealed record PostDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
}

And configure AutoMapper, docs are here.

This is how I fixed my problem.
on my HTML I have this:
<div class="col-7" id="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addPostBtn" data-count="@Model.Posts.Count">Add Post</button>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Posts.Count; i++)
    {
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-4">
          <label asp-for="Posts[@i].Title" class="control-label">Title:</label>
          <input name="Posts[@i].Title" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="Posts[@i].Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
</div>

and on you script section you can do this:
@section Scripts {
  <script>
    const addPostBtn = $('#addPostBtn');
    const postCount = $('#addPostBtn').data("count");
    const container = $('#container');

    addPostBtn.on("click", () => {
      container.append(appendHtml(postCount++));
    });


    function appendHtml(count) {
      return `
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label asp-for="Posts[${count}].Title" class="control-label">Title:</label>
            <input name="Posts[${count}].Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Posts[${count}].Title" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
    };
  </script>
}

The issue with this solution is. When the model state gets validated then the old data is not being preserved. So the users have to retype there post again.
Update:
ok for the data to be preserved you have to add the value property on your input tag.
<input name="Posts[@i].Title" class="form-control" value="@(Model.Posts[@i].Title)" />

